# how can character type variable hold more than one byte in this program?

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with *gcc*. Can anyone tell me, how can this character type variable hold more than one byte? NOTE : This program will echo all characters(more than one) you type. For instance, if u type "thilip", then it will echo as "thilip". each character holds 8-bits(one byte), so i have typed 6 character (6 bytes). Then, How can getchar function assign this value to character type variable which can hold only one byte?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
        putchar(ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the proof that it holds more than one byte?

Comment: @thilip Are you wondering how `ch` which is of `char` type (one byte) can get output values of `getchar` which is `int`? There is implicit `int -> char` cast in your code.

Comment: Kunal, This program will echo all characters(more than one) you type. For instance, if u type "thilip", then it will echo as "thilip". each character holds 8-bits(one byte), so i have typed 6 cahracter       (6 bytes). Then, How can getchar function assign this value to character type variable which can hold only one byte?

Comment: "linux 12.04" God dammit!

Comment: Your `ch` is called a "variable" for a reason... you can change it's value, so over time it can hold many different chars, one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` type variable is of 1 Byte. You can check it by

```
printf("%zu", sizeof(char));
```

If you are wondering that on giving input

```
asdf
```

it is printing

```
asdf
```

because of `ch` holds this `asdf` then you are wrong. `getchar()` reads only one character at a time.
When you input multiple `char`'s then this set of character gets stored in input buffer. Then, `getchar()` reads a character one by one from this input buffer and assign one character at a time to the `char` variable `ch`, and `putchar()` prints it one by one. After each iteration `ch` is overwritten by the new character read by `getchar()`.
You can check that `getchar()` reads only one `char` at a time  by running this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();
    putchar(ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
thilip
```

Output:

```
t
```

### Side note:

`getchar()` returns `int`. You should declare `ch` as `int`.

Answer (score 2):

It can't. Every time `getchar` is called, its previous value is overwritten with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

It is one byte. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: Characters like U+2026(which is '…') have _two_ bytes of data within them. And some can have more.